# c# WCF Server application - access to a file on the server relatively

Tags: c#, file-access

I have a c# server application (WCF) and I have a file saved on that server and i want to access it relatively so every dev machine can work with it.

this is the file path.

> C:\Users\ben\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ **myfile.xml**

the project where i want to access the file from is in:

> C:\Users\ben\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ **MyProject**

what is the best way to access the myfile.xml (relatively)? from MyProject?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you run the project, your current directory will be something like:

`C:\Users\ben\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\`

So you will probably want to do something else.

Include the file in the project and go to File Properties for the file. Select `Copy Always` for the `Copy to Output Directory` setting. The file will then be copied to the same directory as the EXE when compiling/building. That way you can access the file simply by its filename.

Comment: thanks, so how do i access it? I chose always copy, than i try to access it `MyProject/myfile.xml` but it cannot find it.

Comment: The file will not be copied to your project folder, but to the output folder for the project. See "Properties" for the project, and "Build". At the bottom there, you should see the field "Output path", probably with the dir name "bin\". That is where you will find the file, as well as the other files from your project once it is buildt. Exactly as atornblad writes; take note of the last part of the path he uses as an example.

Comment: @Kjartan  Thanks, I see in the bin directory but i cant access it. I am getting : The system cannot find the file specified thanks

Comment: What filename or Uri are you using for opening the file? You should just use something like `File.Open("myfile.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

From your question , what is under stood is that you want to access your project location , without the executable file and folder . To do that try the following code :

```
        string AppPath = System.Environment.CommandLine;
        int pos = AppPath.IndexOf("bin");
        AppPath = AppPath.Remove(pos);
        AppPath += "myfile.xml";
```

Comment: no, I just want to host a static file and access to it in the server. my own config file, or what ever other file that i want to host in my project and access to it relativly. thanks

Comment: @user1, You can access the file just by appending the file name , in this case the xml file.